# In Zend MVC, how do you pass a variable set int the controller, to a layout?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, layout, controller, zend-framework-mvc

I have to pass the page title names and meta information to the layout but not to sure how to do this =/

Comment: What about if the layout is including PHP from another location outside of the MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set you page titles and other info in your controller (if you're planning to change these depending on the action called):

```
$this->view->headTitle('123');
$this->view->headMeta('text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Type', 'http-equiv');
```

And then render them in your layout:

```
echo $this->headTitle() . $this->headMeta();
```

Comment: @codeninja what arguments are you passing to `headMeta()`? It works fine with those from my sample.

Answer (score 1):

check out the placeholder helpers
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder
and
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html